# Trouble with Approximate time sync

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get approximate time sync to work on a project for a few days now. the call back just never seems to fire. I decided to start over and make a couple simple nodes to look at everything from a simpler project, as I've read things on the forums like people struggle to sync more that 2 topics.

So I made a simple publisher node that publishes three header messages on individual topics. and a simple subscriber node that tries to sync the first two topics for now. I did everything following the use guide in the message filter page.

I cant even get the simple example to build ( my original does build). The specific error is 'value' is not a member of 'ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_std::allocator<void>, void>'

I found a forum post that mentioned that a similar error was caused by not using a message with a header. My guess is that I'm doing something small like not initializing the headers properly or something like that. I'll post the code from both nodes and hopefully someone has a suggestion.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "TestPublisher");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Publisher test1_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Header>("test1", 1000);
    ros::Publisher test2_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Header>("test2", 1000);
    ros::Publisher test3_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Header>("test3", 1000);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        std_msgs::Header msg1, msg2, msg3;
        msg1.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        msg2.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        msg3.stamp = ros::Time::now();



        test1_pub.publish(msg1);
        test2_pub.publish(msg2);
        test3_pub.publish(msg3);

        ros::spinOnce();

        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}

#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Header.h"

using namespace message_filters;
void testCallback(const std_msgs::Header::ConstPtr& msg1, const std_msgs::Header::ConstPtr& msg2)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("message 1 " << msg1);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("message 2 " << msg2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "TestSubscriber");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Header> test1_sub(nh, "test1", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Header> test2_sub(nh, "test2", 1);

    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<std_msgs::Header, std_msgs::Header> MySyncPolicy;

    Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), test1_sub, test2_sub);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&testCallback, _1, _2));

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327490/trouble-with-approximate-time-sync/) by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could be wrong, but a "message with a header" is not the same as "a header" (as in: a `std_msgs/Header` doesn't actually contain a header itself).

You may want to try with one of the `Stamped` messages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-07-02**:
That did it. I moved to pointcloud2 as the message type and it started firing. Thanks!

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-07-02**:\

> I could be wrong, but a "message with
> a header" is not the same as "a
> header" (as in: a std_msgs/Header
> doesn't actually contain a header
> itself).
>
> You may want to try with one of the
> Stamped messages. gravatar
> gvdhoorn ( 3 hours ago )

gvdhoorn had the right solution. I still didn't actually have a header in the message type I was using.